Approximate match search in SQLite
See this table:

I want to use Approximate match search
For example
when I search for the word “فاطمه” it shows me records of “فاطمة”
and so on with “احمد” it shows me records of “أحمد”
I don't want to use the REPLACE function
   CREATE TEMP TABLE Names (
    ID INTEGER,
    Name_AR TEXT
);

    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (1, 'فا طمة 1');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (2, 'أحمد 1');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (3, 'خديجة 1');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (4, 'فا طمة 2');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (5, 'أحمد 2');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (6, 'خديجة 2');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (7, 'فاطمه');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (8, 'احمد');
    INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (9, 'خديجه');
    
    
    SELECT * FROM Names; 
    
    SELECT * FROM Names WHERE instr(Name_AR, :Name_AR);//not working Exact
    
    SELECT * FROM Names WHERE REPLACE(Name_AR, 'ة', 'ه') LIKE :Name_AR; Working


can you show us your sql? And maybe a example in latin letters?

This problem only occurs in Arabic letters, while in Latin letters there is no problem

Try using prepared statements. - It helped me once when I had some specialcaracters.

How to use prepared statements.

Here a brief example of a select-statement in Delphi:
Query.SQL.Text := 'Select * from Track  where instr(Name_AR,:Name_AR)'; 
Query.ParamByName('Name_AR').asstring := Search_Variable;
Query.Open;

here a good explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

like this Query
CREATE TEMP TABLE Names (ID INTEGER,Name_AR TEXT);
INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (1, 'فا طمة 1');
INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (2, 'أحمد 1');
INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (3, 'خديجة 1');
INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (4, 'فا طمة 2');
INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (5, 'أحمد 2');
INSERT INTO Names (ID, Name_AR) VALUES (6, 'خديجة 2');
SELECT * FROM Names WHERE instr(Name_AR, :Name_AR);

Structure and data have been added at the top of the question

I made a few trys - and it looks ok to me using instr()!
Can you tell me one thats not correct end what you expect. You can use linenumber or id.

When searching by part of the word, it gives correct results
The format when searching by full word does not give me results
Example:
"فاطمة" <> "فاطمه"
They are supposed to be equal

This may be a workaround:
Define a Table with 1 row containing the searchvalue.
then: select * from Names where instr(name_ar,(select search from search)). I did this because I really had trouble copy-paste this arabic strings.

I did not understand well, please explain more

like this Exemple in search:
SELECT INSTR('فاطمة', 'فاطمة'); //Return 1
SELECT INSTR('فاطمة', 'فاطم');  //Return 1
SELECT INSTR('فاطمة', 'فاطمه'); //Return 0

This works fo me. Why it compares different I dont know.
drop Table if exists search;
CREATE TABLE search (search TEXT);
insert into search (search) VALUES ('فاطمه');

select * from Names where instr(name_ar,(select search from search));


This is not what is required
It is required to bring all records that closely match the name “فاطمه”
which is next:
"فاطمة 1"
"فاطمة 2"
"فاطمه"

Last try:  look for the Like - command. But I'm off - my arabic is not good enough for this problem.

select * from Names where name_ar LIKE '%فاطمه%'
